# WPF: How to a define a custom control's look in designer?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

So I like the fact that the look of custom controls can be re-defined in generic.xaml so I'd like to create one. But my issue is, how do you initially DESIGN (using the designer) the look for the custom control? unlike a user control it doesn't have an attached xaml / designer window. So must do design it all in code?

Comment: Expression Blend gives you a design surface wot work with...

Answer (score 2):

You create a `ResourceDictionary` `XAML` file in which you define the `CustomTemplate`/`Style` for a control, and then merge all such dictionaries in the `Generic.xaml` dictionary.

For instance, define a control style:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement" >
                        <ContentPresenter 
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And in your `Generic.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyButtonStyle.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The result should be that controls of type `Button` are now rendered with the specified style, even in the IDE designer.

Comment: this doesn't answer my questio

Comment: If you update the style, all style carriers bear the changes _in the designer_. If you want to edit _inline_, so to speak in the XAML/Display split-screen, then add a custom control item, design in the designer, then rip it out into a style - but this is elaborate, somewhat.